# Exporting a CA certificate from Android to Android?

Tags: applications, password, google-pixel, certificates

I'm trying to install an openssl CA certificate on my Pixel 5, previously I was able to install it directly through the app I was using on my old Pixel 2 but with the new security measures this is no longer an option and I'm attempting to take this into my hands.
This is my first time trying to do this on any of my phones.

I got the CA certificate off my computer by downloading the app through an android emulator. The file was originally saved as a .dll file and I just changed the end of the file to a .pfk. I believe it is now in the correct format as it recognized by my phone.

When I go to install the ca certificate I am asked for a password to extract the certificate. I opened the file as a text document and read through it thinking I would be able to find it in there. After reading I thought the password was "callback", but that doesn't seem to work.

Is there some kind of application I can run to retrieve the password?

Comment: There is something wrong with your question. A dll files can never be used as pfx file. Only p12 files can be renamed to pfx. May be you should give more details on what certificate (with private key) you want export/import and seven more important for what purpose you need it.